Are There Any Big Brands Using an SPL Token?
Not a technical question but let’s try.
I'm part of a large company with millions of customers, and we're considering creating and launching an SPL token. This token would serve a dual purpose:

It would be both a meme coin and the official company token, people that know our company can buy and hold just because they like us or cause they think it will become a popular token (really possible)
Used for various transactions, such as paying out users, compensating employees (if they choose), and in general integrating into our platform.

Our company sells physical goods, and our users can earn money as creators, so we thought this would be a fun and innovative idea.
My question is: Are there any well-known companies outside of the crypto/blockchain space that have done something similar?

While no major non-crypto companies have launched an SPL token specifically, brands like Reddit, Nike, and Tesla have successfully integrated blockchain-based tokens or cryptocurrencies into their ecosystems, providing a useful model for your venture.
